# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, error-handling

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screenlocked);

    //Retrieve stored ID
    final String STORAGE = "Storage";  
    SharedPreferences unique = getSharedPreferences(STORAGE, 0);
    LoginID = unique.getString("identifier", "");

    //Retrieve stored phone number
    final String phoneNumber = unique.getString("PhoneNumber", "");
    phoneView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);
    phoneView.setText(phoneNumber.toString());

    //Retrieve user input
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    userInput = input.getText().toString();

    //Set login button
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            compareID();
        }
    });
}

public void compareID(){

    if (userInput.equals(LoginID)){
        //phone screen unlocked
        //continue
        Toast.makeText(ScreenLockActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        count += 1;
        input.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(ScreenLockActivity.this, count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I am developing a login `activity` and I would like to record down how many times the user tried to login, so every time there is a login attempt the count will increment by one... but when i run the activity, this error appears in my logcat:

`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1`,

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: you have try after clearing your project from Project-Clean in Eclipse IDE ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is your mistake:

```
Toast.makeText(ScreenLockActivity.this, count, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

the `makeText` you are trying to invoke here, is the `makeText` that takes as second parameter a `resId`. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) for more info. Since you want to print the count value, you have to convert it in a String.

```
String value = String.valueOf(count);
Toast.makeText(ScreenLockActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: @blackbelt, am facing the same error, so can u please tell me how to identify the error line

Comment: @AndroidOptimist it in the stacktrace. In the logcat you will see a lot of red lines, when  the error occurs. you should look for the one that points out in your code

Answer (score 0):

This line should be inside `onClick()` or `compareID()`:

```
userInput = input.getText().toString();
```